# Mongo query timestamp to date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert an int timestamp to a date in an aggregation query:

```js
[
    {$match: {"source": "tomtom"}},
    {$group: {
        "_id": "$date",
        "count": {
          "$sum": 1
        }
    }},
    {$project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "date":{ $convert: { input: "$_id", to: "date" } },
        "count": 1
    }},
    {$sort: {date:1}}
]
```

But, the dates are in the end of January, 1970, I suspect it is because my timestamps are in seconds and this function needs a milliseconds timestamp.

Comment: multiply by 1000

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `$multiply`:

```js
{ $multiply : ["$_id", 1000 ]}
```

Complete query:

```js
[
    {$match: {"source": "tomtom"}},
    {$group: {
        "_id": "$date",
        "count": {
          "$sum": 1
        }
    }},
    {$project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "date":{ $convert: { input: { $multiply : ["$_id", 1000 ]}, to: "date" } },
        "count": 1
    }},
    {$sort: {date:1}}
]
```